# SPUtility.TransferToSuccessPage() throwing Exception

Tags: development, application-pages

in my application page when i m using Sputility.transffertosuccesspage ,its throw an exception, " Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack. " 
The same exception was also occur if we use response.redirect(abc.aspx); but we can resolve this exception with (abc.aspx,false) but how to solve Sputility.transffertosuccesspage exception.

Thanks
SAAD

Comment: i move SPUtility.TransferToSuccessPage outside the try block and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, I believe these methods throw a ThreadAbortException. I'd move them out of your try\catch block.

Comment: yes you are Right John